# Monitoring of event-based SLA violations? (such as file delays)

Tags: monitoring, ftp, sla

Our current SLA's require delivery of a file within a specific time window.  We have quite of few of these files, generated at various times during the day.

I know of external monitoring sites like Site24x7 that will monitor for disruptions to specific services.  For example, if our FTP server goes down, we would get a notification.

But, is there any host service OR server-based software that can monitor our processes and generate notifications when (a) an expected event is delayed more than a designated time, and (b) when the expected event finally occurs?

I'm looking for a notification like, "The file XYZZY.DAT was expected to be posted 91 minutes ago, but it is still not there."

Comment: It is not clear what you want to see, or how you want to see it? Via mail or on a web dashboard? If on a web dashboard, does it mean you want to see the event and there should be details which would state what is the time since the event was generated (time since something should happen)? This would more some "real-time" monitoring.

Comment: If I had to solve this problem in my company I would write a custom plugin for Nagios to do it.

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha -- the goal would be an email or SMS notification to the responsible party, perhaps also triggering some immediate diagnostic program to gather further information

Answer (score 0):

Every usual monitoring tool can do this. See Zabbix, Zenoss, Icinga... or even a stupid home-made scripts. For Zabbix it seems you can use trapper to tell zabbix about an event from your script delivering the files, then you could combine it with simple checks to see if your server hosting those files is remotely available. All mentioned applications have dashboard but also can send alerts to mails, phones, pages, whatever.